# Disable parallel build for specific plugin in Maven

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, checkstyle

I build my project using **maven** with **-T** option. Sometimes the build failed with random **checkstyle** error.

Is it possible to disable **-T** option for *specific* plugin (**checkstyle**) and block execution of this plugin in parallel?

Just in case attaching stacktraces:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.16:check (validate) on project yyy-1: Execution validate of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.16:check failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.16:check (validate) on project yyy-1: Execution validate of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.16:check failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    ...
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:185)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ...
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution validate of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.16:check failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.AbstractJavadocCheck.visitToken(AbstractJavadocCheck.java:182)
    ...
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.process(Checker.java:265)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.exec.DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.executeCheckstyle(DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.CheckstyleViolationCheckMojo.execute(CheckstyleViolationCheckMojo.java:538)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 12 more
```

or

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.16:check (validate) on project xxx-2: You have 1 Checkstyle violation. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.16:check (validate) on project xxx-2: You have 1 Checkstyle violation.
    ...
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:185)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ...
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: You have 1 Checkstyle violation.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.CheckstyleViolationCheckMojo.execute(CheckstyleViolationCheckMojo.java:588)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: It is either Checkstyle or the Maven Plugin. You should raise an issue with Checkstyle on it's GitHub project page. If this is fixed in 6.11, I will include it in the next Maven Checkstyle Plugin version.

Comment: reported: [plugin](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCHECKSTYLE-310) + [checkstyle](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/2237)

Comment: Actually it's about how Maven Plugin uses Checkstyle. Checkstyle is totally-not-thread-safe and uses static state for caching. It can be run in parallel only from two separate class loaders.

Comment: @MichalKordas is it possible to specify fork mode together with -T maven option?

Comment: @aholub7x, I'm not sure. But you can use latest Checkstyle and check if problem goes away after my fix in https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/commit/ed89c9edb524243b0df61e83a5ac0930f070e6d7

Comment: Thanks @MichalKordas ! I use the fixed version since release and didn't catch the error again!

Answer (score 2):

Checkstyle up to version 6.11 didn't have even simple thread safety. Javadoc checks were using static cache shared across all executions of Checkstyle in single JVM.

From version 6.11 on I've replaced static cache with thread-local cache which is equally fast, but gives basic thread safety. It makes possible to use **-T** option with Maven and Checkstyle.